# C# - Referencia a objetos y vectores

Tags: c#

Tengo un problema en donde mediante un instacio un nuevo objeto para luego este objeto para a ser parte de un vector de objetos de este mismo tipo, pero cuando le solicito un dato de vuelta de 2 indices diferentes del vector, me devuelve la misma informacion.

Nota: vectermi es un metodo el cual va ampliando el tamaño del vector de ubjetos debido a que cuando uno lo inicializa tiene que indicar la cantidad de elementos que va contener

```
       if (opcion == "1")
        {
            terminal x = new terminal();

            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese nombre de la terminal");
            x.ntermi = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese nombre de la ciudad");

            x.ciudad = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("La terminal fue dada de alta correctamente");
            Ltermi = vectermi(Ltermi, x);

            Console.WriteLine(Ltermi[0].ntermi);
            Console.WriteLine(Ltermi[Ltermi.Length-1].ntermi);

            Console.ReadKey();
            menurecorridos();

        }
```

//METODO VECTERMI

```
public static terminal[] vectermi(terminal[]z,terminal x)
    {
        if (z.Length == 1)
        {
            z[0] = x;
            return z;
        }


            terminal[] vec = new terminal[z.Length + 1];
            for (int cont = 0; cont < z.Length; cont++)
            {
                vec[cont] = z[cont];
            }
            vec[vec.Length - 1] = x;
            return vec;

    }
```

La clase terminal tiene 2 campos: `ntermi` (que es nombre de terminal) y `ciudad`. Al entrar al `if` instancio un nuevo objeto terminal, mediante el ingreso de teclado lleno esos campos, (vamos suponer que el dato en `ntermi=T1` `ciudad= blabla`), luego repito la entrada para ingresar otro dato mas de otro nuevo objeto terminal (esta vez es `ntermi = T2` y `ciudad= vlavla`.

Entonces yo le pido como se ve en el código , el elemento del principio y el del final, es decir `terminal[0].ntermi` y `terminal[terminal.Lenght-1].ntermi` pero solo me da output T2 T2 cuando tendria que ser T1 y T2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está aqui:

```
if (z.Length == 1)
{
    z[0] = x;
    return z;
}
```

Como empiezas con un array de tamaño 1, siempre que llamas a esta funcion, siempre te devuelve el mismo array con el mismo tamaño.

La solución es facil. Inicializa tu array `Ltermi` con tamaño 0:

```
terminal[] Ltermi = new terminal[0];
```

Y elimina del metodo `vectermi` el codigo que te puse arriba que comprueba el tamaño del array.

Comment: gracias otra vez